# How to dispatch an action when component did mount using Hooks in a connected function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

[React-Redux]

I'm looking for a proper approach to dispatch a mapped action that contains a promise to fetch some data from the server and change state in the store when component mounts.

The action creator is binded to component props using { bindActionCreators } from "redux" in { connect } from "react-redux";

Currently I'm using useFetch Hook with a skip flag, but I think it is not a good practice because the effect is fired on every state change and it just don't runs because of the flag.

```
    const [skipUpdate, setSkipUpdate] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!skipUpdate) {
            props.fetchData();
            setSkipUpdate(true);
        }
    }, [skipUpdate, props]);
```

I expect the "dispatch effect" just be fired when component did mount, an not on every state change too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use effect with an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => { props.fetchData(); }, []);
```

This will only run on initial mount.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works, but gives me a warn:

```React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect```

I can just ignore the warn, but it makes me think if this is completely OK.

Comment: You can ignore the warning for your use case - you don’t want to refetch if `fetchData` prop changes do you?  It sounds like a lint warning btw. If so, just suppress it in this instance

Comment: You probably shouldn't ignore that warning. ESLint for hooks *really* wants to you declare all your dependencies in `useEffect`. You want to try to rewrite your effect to be something like `const { fetchData } = props; useEffect(() => {fetchData()}, [fetchData]). Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639141/how-to-do-fetch-with-react-hooks-eslint-enforcing-exhaustive-deps-rule-which/56640977