# How to do fetch with React Hooks; ESLint enforcing `exhaustive-deps` rule, which causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, eslint, react-hooks

I'm pretty new to React hooks in general, and very new to `useSelector` and `useDispatch` in `react-redux`, but I'm having trouble executing a simple `get` request when my component loads. I want the `get` to happen only once (when the component initially loads). I thought I knew how to do that, but I'm running into an ESLint issue that's preventing me from doing what I understand to be legal code.

I have this hook where I'm trying to abstract my state code:

```
export const useState = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.data);

  return {
    data: data,
    get: (props) => dispatch(actionCreators.get(props))
  };
};
```

Behind the above function, there's a network request that happens via `redux-saga` and `axios`, and has been running in production code for some time. So far, so good. Now I want to use it in a functional component, so I wrote this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from './my-state-file';

export default () => {
  const myState = useState();

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      myState.get();
      return () => {};
    },
    []
  );
  return <div>hello, world</div>;
};
```

What I expected to happen was that because my `useEffect` has an empty array as the second argument, it would only execute once, so the `get` would happen when the component loaded, and that's it.

However, I have ESLint running on save in Atom, and every time I save, it changes that second `[]` argument to be `[myState]`, the result of which is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from './my-state-file';

export default () => {
  const myState = useState();

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      myState.get();
      return () => {};
    },
    [myState]
  );
  return <div>hello, world</div>;
};
```

If I load this component, then the get runs every single render, which of course is the exact opposite of what I want to have happen. I opened this file in a text editor that does *not* have ESLint running on save, so when I was able to save `useEffect` with a blank `[]`, it worked.

So I'm befuddled. My guess is the pattern I'm using above is not correct, but I have no idea what the "right" pattern is.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Based on Robert Cooper's answer, and the linked article from Dan Abramov, I did some more experimenting. I'm not all the way there yet, but I managed to get things working.

The big change was that I needed to add a `useCallback` around my dispatch functions, like so:

```
export const useState = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.data);
  const get = React.useCallback((props) => dispatch({type: 'MY_ACTION', payload:props}), [
    dispatch
  ]);

  return {
    data: data,
    get: get,
  };
};
```

I must admit, I don't fully understand why I need useCallback there, but it works.

Anyway, then my component looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from './my-state-file';

export default () => {
  const {get, data}  = useState();

  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      get();
      return () => {};
    },
    [get]
  );
  return <div>{do something with data...}</div>;
};
```

The real code is a bit more complex, and I'm hoping to abstract the `useEffect` call out of the component altogether and put it into either the `useState` custom hook, or another hook imported from the same `my-state-file` file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem you're encountering is that the value of `myState` in your dependency array isn't the same value or has a different JavaScript object reference on every render. The way to get around this would be to pass a memoized or cached version of `myState` as a dependency to your `useEffect`.

You could try using [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to return a memoized version of your state return by your custom `useState`. This might look something like this:

```
export const useState = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector((state) => state.data);

  return useMemo(() => ({
    data: data,
    get: (props) => dispatch(actionCreators.get(props))
  }), [props]);
};
```

Here's what Dan Abramov has to say regarding infinite loops in `useEffect` methods:

> **Question: Why do I sometimes get an infinite refetching loop?**
>
> This can happen if you’re doing data fetching in an effect without the second dependencies argument. Without it, effects run after every render — and setting the state will trigger the effects again. An infinite loop may also happen if you specify a value that always changes in the dependency array. You can tell which one by removing them one by one. However, removing a dependency you use (or blindly specifying []) is usually the wrong fix. Instead, fix the problem at its source. For example, functions can cause this problem, and putting them inside effects, hoisting them out, or wrapping them with useCallback helps. To avoid recreating objects, useMemo can serve a similar purpose.

Full article here: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still chewing on it. I thought perhaps the easy fix was to destructure `myState` so that my effect code would be  `React.useEffect( () => { get(); return () => {}; }, [get] );` (similar to Abramov's `[dispatch]` example from the article) but that didn't change the behavior, so I'm clearly still missing something. `useMemo` didn't work as you suggested, because `props` isn't available until `get` and `clear` are executed. So I'm still either missing something simple and stupid, or my mental model of how this all works isn't right yet. I'll keep at it!

Comment: I updated my question with one possible solution. I'm not 100% happy with it yet, but I've got something that works at least. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ah ok, glad you were able to figure.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure yet that hooks are actually a nicer pattern than HOCs. Everybody keeps saying they are, so I suppose I'll just have to trust that eventually they'll click and my coding life will be beautiful. I know it's just supposed to be straight Javascript, which theoretically makes things nicer, but lifecycle stuff like `useEffect` and `useCallback` make hooks hard to reason about when you're looking at the code.

Comment: I tend to agree. It's not intuitive what `useEffect` and `useCallback` do compared to the lifecycle methods that are available through classes.